# Wifi with Broadcom BCM4313 does not work

Tags: 12.04, wireless, broadcom

I just installed 12.04. At the beginning, the network manager was not showing the wireless networks.

The output of `lspci -vvnn | grep 14e4` is the following:

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller [14e4:4727] (rev 01)
```

After reading some posts in this forum, I did this:

1. Removed `bcmwl-kernel-source` using Synaptic Package Manager;
2. installed `firmware-b43-installer` and `b43-fwcutter` again with Synaptic Package Manager.

Now, I am able to see all available wireless networks, but it never connects successfully. The wireless icon stays blinking for a while before saying

> Wireless Network - Disconnected.

Also, I never could do the thing with **Additional Drivers**. I always get an error. This is the log:

```
FATAL: Module wl not found.
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.8.0-29-generic

2013-08-28 21:50:55,489 WARNING: modinfo for module wl failed: ERROR: modinfo: could not find module wl

2013-08-28 21:50:55,490 WARNING: /sys/module/wl/drivers does not exist, cannot rebind wl driver
2013-08-28 21:50:55,532 DEBUG: BroadcomWLHandler enabled(): kmod disabled, bcm43xx: blacklisted, b43: blacklisted, b43legacy: blacklisted
2013-08-28 21:51:20,917 DEBUG: BroadcomWLHandler enabled(): kmod disabled, bcm43xx: blacklisted, b43: blacklisted, b43legacy: blacklisted
2013-08-28 21:51:20,942 DEBUG: BroadcomWLHandler enabled(): kmod disabled, bcm43xx: blacklisted, b43: blacklisted, b43legacy: blacklisted
2013-08-28 21:51:20,974 DEBUG: BroadcomWLHandler enabled(): kmod disabled, bcm43xx: blacklisted, b43: blacklisted, b43legacy: blacklisted
```

I don't know anymore if I am supposed to install the module `wl` or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Getting this device 14e4:4727 working properly in 12.04 is indeed challenging. I recommend you do not install the STA driver from 'Additional Drivers' and if it is installed now, remove it:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge bcmwl-kernel source
sudo modprobe -r wl
sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-bcm43.conf
```

If that file doesn't exist, that's fine, just proceed.

```
sudo modprobe brcmsmac
```

Now does your wireless work as expected? If not, let's try a newer driver. With a temporary wired ethernet connection,do:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-backports-modules-cw-3.3-precise-generic
```

Detach the ethernet and reboot.

Comment: With or without istalling backports??

Comment: I installed backports. I did everything you said and it started working :) however, sometimes it disconnects and I have to click again my wireless network to make it work. It was already like that when I had Debian, so I am kind of used to it